# I do not understand why elementary operations are made to find Eigen values.

Tags: linear-algebra

We where just introduced to eigen values and the following bugs me.

Polynomial(lambda) = det(A - lambda I) = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
1 - \lambda & 1  & 1\\ 
 1 & 1-\lambda  & 1\\ 
 1& 1& 1-\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}

Then they do Line 1 - line 2 =  \begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda & \lambda  & 0\\ 
 1 & 1-\lambda  & 1\\ 
 1& 1& 1-\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}

Then they put lambda out of the matrix and compute the det.

Now what I don't understand isn't how to find the eigen value **but more about what is the objective of doing the elementary operation. Is there a common pattern like the gauss-jordan REF.**

Comment: The objective of doing the elementary operations is to make the matrix upper triangle. Which makes the determinant equal to the product of the diagonal entries which is convenient.

Comment: it is not really needed. There is that "rule of Sarrus" that allows us to write out a 3 by 3 determinant. However, when the entries have the extra $\lambda,$ I guess it gets long, so they gave an alternative

Answer (score 1):

Recall that performing elementary row oeperations does not change the (magnitude of) determinant. In other words, $|\det A|=|\det A'|$ if $A'$ is the result of elementary row operations on $A$. There is of course no need to perform these operations, since computing directly will lead to the correct result, but doing so would make the determinant easier to compute. All of this has nothing to do with eigenvalues per se, just in computing determinants (easily).